# mapping geo polygon Elastic Search/Kibana 5.3

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I have 20,000 geojson files in this format:

```
{
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [long,lat],
                [long,lat],
                [long,lat],
                [long,lat],
                [long,lat]
            ]
        ]
    },
```

All the mappings I’ve attempted with geo_shape and geo_point have either not shown up in Kibana or show up in kibana, but with no data. What is the best way to map this to index many files? (If no good way, my next thought was to create a centerpoint for each file if I can’t use all the coordinates. Perhaps take the first long,lat array and make that the geo_point center point for every json file. Not sure how to go about this either)

This is the default mapping from ES when I index without changing anything:

```
{
  "indexname" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "my_type" : {
        "properties" : {
          "geometry" : {
            "properties" : {
              "coordinates" : {
                "type" : "float"
              },
              "type" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
```

**UPDATE**
Here is my new mapping:

```
{
  "indexname" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "my_type" : {
        "properties" : {
          "geometry" : {
            "type" : "geo_shape",
            "tree" : "quadtree",
            "precision" : "1.0m"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
```

However, when I go to kibana I'm still getting an error when trying to visualize on enhanced tilemap:

```
No Compatible Fields: The "indexname" index pattern does not contain any of the following field types: geo_point
```

**EDIT2**
This is my command to create the mapping:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/indexname" -d "{\"mappings\" : {\"my_type\" : {\"properties\" : {\"geometry\" : {\"type\":\"geo_shape\", \"tree\": \"quadtree\", \"precision\": \"1m\"}}}}}"
```

I'm indexing my files by looping through and sending a post request:

```
r = requests.post(url_of_index, data=file(jsonfiles).read())
```

When I try to change the type to a geo_point and then index my files, I run into a mapper parser exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create your own mapping containing a [`geo_shape`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html) type as ES does not infer that from your GeoJSON documents by itself.

```
PUT indexname
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "geometry": {
          "type": "geo_shape",
          "tree": "quadtree",
          "precision": "1m"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After creating this index and mapping, you'll be able to index your GeoJSON files:

```
PUT indexname/my_type/1
{
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [long,lat],
            [long,lat],
            [long,lat],
            [long,lat],
            [long,lat]
        ]
    ]
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

According to our discussion, you might need to create a new `geo_point` field in your mapping, like this:

```
PUT indexname
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "geo_shape",
          "tree": "quadtree",
          "precision": "1m"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then from your Python code, you need to create that new field by reading the first coordinate from the JSON file, something like the pseudo code below:

```
import json

doc = json.loads(file(jsonfiles).read())
# create the new location field
doc['location'] = doc['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0]
r = requests.post(url_of_index, data=json.dumps(doc))
```

Comment: I can do that, but still get same error No Compatible Fields: The "indexname" index pattern does not contain any of the following field types: geo_point

Comment: Maybe you should update your question and show the commands you're running and the error you're getting.

Comment: updated--I want to try to visualize something on the enhanced tilemap. But, geo_shape does not seem to be supported. How can I work with array of polygons as a point?

Comment: Can you show the commands you're running to index your document and the error you're getting? Also show what you're trying to do in Kibana. I'd like to understand why ES/Kibana is complaining about a `geo_point`.

Comment: See Edit2 above

Comment: Also worth noting that `geo_shape` aggregations are not yet supported in Kibana: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2576

Comment: Since your files contain GeoJSON data, the only valid data type you can use is `geo_shape`, not `geo_point`. But then as stated in my previous comment, Kibana doesn't yet support `geo_shape` aggregations.

Comment: Ok I was under the impression it was supported for enhanced_tilemap. Is there a way I can just use one array of the coordinates. E.g. Coordinates[0][0] and make those a point so I can at least see some time series information? (Let me know if moving this discussion to chat is better)

Comment: Indeed, in your indexing code, you could add another `geo_point` field in your mapping (as initially) and when reading your GeoJSON file, initialize that new field with the first coordinate of the `coordinates` array.

Comment: This command doesn't seem to access the first array because nothing shows up in the tilemap...any ideas? `curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/indexname" -d "{\"mappings\" : {\"my_type" : {\"properties\" : {\"geometry\" : {\"properties\": {\"coordinates[0][0]\" : {\"type\":\"geo_point\"}}}}}}}"` I'm a bit confused about how to create what you just said.

Comment: The part I'm confused how to do is: " initialize that new field with the first coordinate of the coordinates array. "

Comment: You need to do it from your python code. See my updated answer

Comment: `File "indexfiles.py", line 14, in send_post
    doc['location'] = doc['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: That was pseudo code :-) I've updated my answer by including a JSON encoder/decoder.

Comment: ah thank you!!! This was the biggest help, I've been struggling with that for a week.

Comment: That's great if I could help ;-)